# Can't use TRANSLOCO with Storybook in Angular Lib

Tags: storybook, transloco

i'm working on an Angular 13 lib and i want to implement storybook and all lib's compontents include TRANSLOCO.
So, when i create stories i can't see those because i have issues like this:

> NG0302: The pipe 'transloco' could not be found in the
> 'InputTextComponent' component!. Find more at
> https://angular.io/errors/NG0302 Error: NG0302: The pipe 'transloco'
> could not be found in the 'InputTextComponent' component!. Find more
> at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302
> at getPipeDef (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:152096:11)
> at ɵɵpipe (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:152043:15)
> at InputTextComponent_Template (ng:///InputTextComponent.js:72:9)
> at executeTemplate (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:137642:5)
> at renderView (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:137371:7)
> at renderComponent$1 (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:138906:3)
> at renderChildComponents (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:137206:5)
> at renderView (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:137405:7)
> at renderComponent$1 (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:138906:3)
> at renderChildComponents (http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_ngneat_transloco_fesm2015_ngneat-transloco_js-node_modules_storybook_add-e00a9f.iframe.bundle.js:137206:5)

thank's to everyone will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved importing TranslocoModule in moduleMetadata. So the results of story is:

```
export default { 
  title: 'storytitle', 
  component: 'storycomponent',
  decorators: [ 
    moduleMetadata({ 
     imports: [ TranslocoModule ] 
    }) 
  ],
} as Meta
```

Comment: I still get the error: `NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken TRANSLOCO_TRANSPILER!`